# Facing some issue in database "Allowed Memory Exhausted"

Tags: php, database, magento

while installing a mangento theme using quick start process, after giving database details I am facing following error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 26580441 bytes) in
>   /home/sow/public_html/sayitlouddotin/app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Sample.php
>   on line 99

please help me

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=Fatal+error:+Allowed+memory+size+of+33554432+bytes+exhausted+%28tried+to+allocate+26580441+bytes%29+in&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=8UoxU-zTCc-Ejwf1xICQAw&gws_rd=cr#channel=fflb&q=Fatal+error%3A+Allowed+memory+size+of+33554432+bytes+exhausted+magento&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=off

Comment: Typical PHP out of memory error caused by not giving Magento enough resources, **database is working fine**, memory_limit is set to 32M (33,554,432) and needs to be a **minimum of 256M-512M**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory limit in your php.ini file. Go to the php folder open php.ini file, and find this line

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

and increase the memory

```
memory_limit = 2000M
```

or alternatively you can increase the limit directly from your php file

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

Comment: hi navneet thnx for ur response.. I increase the memory memory_limit = 2000M  but still facing the same problem

Comment: add code in magento_root/index.php file at top: ini_set("memory_limit",'1024M'); and Comment out "php_value memory_limit 512M" in your .htaccess file.

Comment: where i can find magento_root/index.php file